# jest function not called after running promise

Tags: jestjs

I am trying to test the methods after resolving a promise using Jest and enzyme. My component/functional code:

```
// Functional Code
let functionAfterAsync = () => {
  console.log('functionAfterAsync called');
}
const asyncFunction = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => resolve());
}
const functionWithAsyncCode = () => {
  // ... some more code here
  console.log('functionWithAsyncCode');
  asyncFunction().then((res: any) => {
    functionAfterAsync();
  })
}
```

My test:

```
functionAfterAsync = jest.fn();
// Tests
describe('<Async Test />', () => {
    it('Call function after promise', () => {
      functionWithAsyncCode();
      expect(functionAfterAsync).toBeCalled();
    })
});
```

But `functionAfterAsync` is not getting called and the error I am getting is:
`expect(jest.fn()).toBeCalled()    Expected mock function to have been called.`

Is there any way to do this. Thanks for the help!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to [wait for the `Promise` to resolve](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) before asserting that `functionAfterAsync` has been called.

The easiest way to do that is to return the `Promise` from `functionWithAsyncCode`:

```js
const functionWithAsyncCode = () => {
  console.log('functionWithAsyncCode');
  return asyncFunction().then(() => {  // return the Promise
    functionAfterAsync();
  })
}
```

...then [wait for it to resolve](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#async-await) in your test:

```js
it('Call function after promise', async () => {  // use an async test function
  await functionWithAsyncCode();  // wait for the Promise to resolve
  expect(functionAfterAsync).toBeCalled();  // SUCCESS
})
```

---

Alternatively, you can assert in a `.then` and [return the `Promise` from your test function](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous#promises):

```js
it('Call function after promise', () => {
  return functionWithAsyncCode().then(() => {  // return the Promise
    expect(functionAfterAsync).toBeCalled();  // SUCCESS
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. Just another question: How do I fail the test if the assertion inside `then` is failing. Currently it just shows as a warning `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch().`

Comment: @SaravananS make sure you return the `Promise` from your test function